# Internet Explorer 10 (Metro App) on Windows 8 Pro (RTM) crash

Tags: crash, windows-8, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10

Internet Explorer 10 (Metro App) on Windows 8 Pro (RTM) does not start and crash with this error:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          27/08/2012 19:21:29
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DELL-OPE3.red.aseinfo.com.sv
Description:
Faulting application name: iexplore.exe, version: 10.0.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50107ebe
Faulting module name: iertutil.dll, version: 10.0.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50109c90
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000172f0b
Faulting process id: 0xadc
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd84bb737cfa16
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\iertutil.dll
Report Id: b1597df3-f0ae-11e1-be78-88532e15da73
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-08-28T01:21:29.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>7612</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DELL-OPE3.red.aseinfo.com.sv</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>iexplore.exe</Data>
    <Data>10.0.9200.16384</Data>
    <Data>50107ebe</Data>
    <Data>iertutil.dll</Data>
    <Data>10.0.9200.16384</Data>
    <Data>50109c90</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>0000000000172f0b</Data>
    <Data>adc</Data>
    <Data>01cd84bb737cfa16</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\WINDOWS\system32\iertutil.dll</Data>
    <Data>b1597df3-f0ae-11e1-be78-88532e15da73</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you tell if Winodws created a Windows Error report (.wer) file?  Were there any other event log entries as a result of the error?

Comment: After this error message, the log shows another error with this message: "Package DefaultBrowser_NOPUBLISHERID was terminated because it took too long to suspend.".  But I believe that was a direct result of the previous error.

Comment: Run `sfc /scannow` in an elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This is an access-violation ("segfault") in Internet Explorer, ostensibly from inside the iertutil.dll module which is a key component of the Internet Explorer Application.

If I were you, I'd take a look in add/remove programs to see if there are any toolbars you might have added recently and remove them.

Alternatively, if you have an anti-virus product installed, it may be useful for you to post that fact - many anti-virus products do not yet properly support Windows 8, and this may be the cause of your problem (you may have to use a different anti-virus product until your current one supports Windows 8).

Finally, this may just be a bug in Internet Explorer. Ensure that Windows Error Reporting is enabled, and Microsoft will receive the crash dump. Microsoft are actively watching the error-reporting logs and many Windows Update patches are issued on the basis of crash dumps received from WER.

Other than that, you don't have many options. You'll just have sit back, turn on Windows Updates and wait for it to fix itself.

Comment: SecurityMatt: 

I did reset the Internet Options to the default factory settings (all extensions are disabled) and the error generated is the same.

About antivirus software, I have Microsoft Defender that was installed by default in Windows 8.

So, I think that maybe is a bug in Internet Explorer 10 and Windows 8.

For now, I will change my default browser to Google Chrome, as I did in Windows 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features and remove any software that looks suspicious or that you don't need.  Remove any free games, toolbars, shopping assistants, search assistants, and anything unsigned.
- Download and run [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and look at what's starting when you computer boots.  Disable anything you don't need and/or that's unsigned.  Make sure to give the Services tab a good look.
- Apply all outstanding Windows Updates.
- Uninstall and reinstall Adobe Reader, Adobe Flash, and Java.  If you don't use Java, don't reinstall it.
- Create a new user account, copy your data to it, and delete your old one.